# Picking up attachments from Outlook Compose window

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

My Addin opens up in New Mail Window, and this is opened through Outlook as well as MAPI or mailTo. Now user can add attachment with this mail, but I send the mail through code (being my requirement), now I try to pick up attachments from current open new mail windows this way:-

```
private Outlook.Attachments GetAttachments()
{
    Outlook.Inspector inspector = this.inspectorWrapper.Inspector;
    Outlook.MailItem myMailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)inspector.CurrentItem;
    var attachments = myMailItem.Attachments;
    return attachments;
}
```

Then During my Send Method I try to access it this way:-

```
for (int i = 0; i <= attachments.Count; i++)
{
    eMail.Attachments.Add(attachments[i].PathName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, 1, attachments[i].FileName);
}
```

attachments is the same object returned through above method, it does show correct attachment count (e.g 2 in my example case).

But it throws an "index outside bounds of array error" when I try to access thisattachments[i] in the code snippet above.
Not sure why this occurs.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

**Edit:**

I open up the compose window, and attach files manually or from excel etc., then I try to fetch attachments from current New Mail Item inspector this way:-

```
private Outlook.Attachments GetAttachments()
{
    Outlook.Inspector inspector = this.inspectorWrapper.Inspector;
    Outlook.MailItem myMailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)inspector.CurrentItem;
    var attachments = myMailItem.Attachments;
    return attachments;
}
```

I do get attachment count to be 2 when I attach two files and the name is also there when I'm trying to access it attachments[1].FileName but the path is coming to be null.
How can I save these attachments to the mail I'm trying to send pro grammatically?

Answer (score 0):

All collections in Outlook (including Attachments) is 1 based, not 0:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= attachments.Count; i++)
```

Comment: That worked, thanks but "attachments[i].PathName" is coming to be null. so I'm getting error "Cannot add the attachment; no data source was provided."

Comment: PathName is always empty unless you are dealing with a "by reference" attachment. You must save the attachment from one email to a temporary folder (Attachment.SaveAsFile), then add that file to another message using Attachments.Add. If you want to skip saving the attachments to te hfile system, you might ant to look into Redemption - its RDOMail.Attachments.Add method allows to pass another attachment as an argument.